# SQL query to limit results based on Priority value

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, oracle19c

I am looking for some help with the following task.
I am selecting records from MY_TABLE having ASSET_TYPE existing in mapping table MAP_RECRF_ASSET_TYPE but I am getting duplicated TECHNICAL_IDs.

For this purpose I have added PRIORITY column in MAP_RECRF_ASSET_TYPE and in the results I would like to have only one record for each TECHNICAL_ID having ASSET_TYPE from MAP_RECRF_ASSET_TYPE table but also with the lowest value of PRIORITY (there will always be only 1 record for the same value of PRIORITY).

My DB is Oracle 19c.

Would greatly appreciate helping me with this code. Thanks

My current query:

```
with MY_TABLE as (
select '1111' as TECHNICAL_ID, 'NOTIONALCR' as ASSET_TYPE from dual union all
select '1111' as TECHNICAL_ID, '50000'      as ASSET_TYPE from dual union all
select '2222' as TECHNICAL_ID, 'FWDNOTLCR'  as ASSET_TYPE from dual union all
select '2222' as TECHNICAL_ID, '50000'      as ASSET_TYPE from dual union all
select '3333' as TECHNICAL_ID, '50000'      as ASSET_TYPE from dual union all
select '3333' as TECHNICAL_ID, 'DUMMY'      as ASSET_TYPE from dual
),

MAP_RECRF_ASSET_TYPE as (
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'NOTIONALCR' as ASSET_TYPE, 1 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'NOTIONALDB' as ASSET_TYPE, 1 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'FWDNOTLCR'  as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'FWDNOTLDR'  as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'SWOFFBALCR' as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'SWOFFBALDR' as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'SWFWNOTLCR' as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'SWFWNOTLDB' as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, '50000'      as ASSET_TYPE, 3 as PRIORITY from dual
)
                SELECT *
                FROM MY_TABLE x
                WHERE
                    x.ASSET_TYPE IN (
                        SELECT ASSET_TYPE
                        FROM MAP_RECRF_ASSET_TYPE
                        WHERE APPLICATION = 'SW');
```

-- Current results:

```
TECHNICAL_ID    ASSET_TYPE
1111    NOTIONALCR
1111    50000
2222    FWDNOTLCR
2222    50000
3333    50000
```

-- Expected results:

```
TECHNICAL_ID    ASSET_TYPE
1111    NOTIONALCR
2222    FWDNOTLCR
3333    50000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add another CTe where you join both tables, it would select one of the priorities and add a row nmuber sorted by the priority

```
with MY_TABLE as (
select '1111' as TECHNICAL_ID, 'NOTIONALCR' as ASSET_TYPE from dual union all
select '1111' as TECHNICAL_ID, '50000'      as ASSET_TYPE from dual union all
select '2222' as TECHNICAL_ID, 'FWDNOTLCR'  as ASSET_TYPE from dual union all
select '2222' as TECHNICAL_ID, '50000'      as ASSET_TYPE from dual union all
select '3333' as TECHNICAL_ID, '50000'      as ASSET_TYPE from dual union all
select '3333' as TECHNICAL_ID, 'DUMMY'      as ASSET_TYPE from dual
),

MAP_RECRF_ASSET_TYPE as (
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'NOTIONALCR' as ASSET_TYPE, 1 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'NOTIONALDB' as ASSET_TYPE, 1 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'FWDNOTLCR'  as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'FWDNOTLDR'  as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'SWOFFBALCR' as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'SWOFFBALDR' as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'SWFWNOTLCR' as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, 'SWFWNOTLDB' as ASSET_TYPE, 2 as PRIORITY from dual union all
select 'SW' as APPLICATION, '50000'      as ASSET_TYPE, 3 as PRIORITY from dual
), CTE AS (
 
                SELECT x.TECHNICAL_ID,x.ASSET_TYPE,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.TECHNICAL_ID ORDER BY mrat.PRIORITY) rn
                FROM MY_TABLE x JOIN MAP_RECRF_ASSET_TYPE mrat 
  ON x.ASSET_TYPE = mrat.ASSET_TYPE
                WHERE 
                   mrat.APPLICATION = 'SW')
SELECT TECHNICAL_ID,ASSET_TYPE FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

| TECHNICAL_ID | ASSET_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | NOTIONALCR |
| 2222 | FWDNOTLCR |
| 3333 | 50000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Bn46Tm6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN`  and then the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to find the lowest priority for each `technical_id`:

```sql
with MY_TABLE (technical_id, asset_type) as (
select '1111', 'NOTIONALCR' from dual union all
select '1111', '50000'      from dual union all
select '2222', 'FWDNOTLCR'  from dual union all
select '2222', '50000'      from dual union all
select '3333', '50000'      from dual union all
select '3333', 'DUMMY'      from dual
),
MAP_RECRF_ASSET_TYPE (application, asset_type, priority) as (
select 'SW', 'NOTIONALCR', 1 from dual union all
select 'SW', 'NOTIONALDB', 1 from dual union all
select 'SW', 'FWDNOTLCR' , 2 from dual union all
select 'SW', 'FWDNOTLDR' , 2 from dual union all
select 'SW', 'SWOFFBALCR', 2 from dual union all
select 'SW', 'SWOFFBALDR', 2 from dual union all
select 'SW', 'SWFWNOTLCR', 2 from dual union all
select 'SW', 'SWFWNOTLDB', 2 from dual union all
select 'SW', '50000'     , 3 from dual
)
SELECT technical_id, asset_type
FROM   (
  SELECT t.technical_id,
         t.asset_type,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY t.technical_id
           ORDER BY a.priority
         ) AS rn
  FROM   MY_TABLE t
         INNER JOIN MAP_RECRF_ASSET_TYPE a
         ON t.asset_type = a.asset_type
  WHERE  a.application = 'SW'
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which outputs:

| TECHNICAL_ID | ASSET_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | NOTIONALCR |
| 2222 | FWDNOTLCR |
| 3333 | 50000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HjMmCbcl)